# device replay is not working for web edit using qtp

Tags: qtp

In one of my Web page there is a webedit which can accept upto 250 characters. Below of that webedit there is an another webedit showing the number of characters left.

While I can enter the characters in the first webebit using qtp, that number of characters left is not being updated.

I have already used device replay option but unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: Please show the code what you´ve tried, no matter how bad it failed. Also include a detailed description of what you mean by "is not working". Also make sure you read the FAQ so you know what a good question should look like here, so you get quick and helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean device replay itself is not working, or after using that as well number of characters left is not getting updated?

In order to show the number of characters left in webedit, developers generally use javascript which changes the message to (maxlength of the text field - max length of the field value) left. This javascript is associated with some event of the textbox like onkeyup when the key is released when the focus is on textbox etc.

When this events are triggered a javascript function is called and the message is updated.

With QTP set methods generally it sets the value of the textbox in which the events associated to the control are not triggered.

In order to trigger those events you can use below methods(whichever is helpful for you, you can try using it)

*1. Try just clicking the textbox again, sometimes this also do the trick in some applications*

```
Browser("Test").Page("Test").WebEdit("Test").Set "Test"
Browser("Test").Page("Test").WebEdit("Test").Click
```

*2. You can try using the FireEvent method in QTP*

```
Browser("Test").Page("Test").WebEdit("Test").Set "India"
Browser("Test").Page("Test").WebEdit("Test").FireEvent "onclick"
```

Note - Do try other events like onkeydown, onkeyup,onkeypress,onblur etc

*3. You can use the Sendkeys for which you will have to create a shell object first
Example*

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Browser("Test").Page("Test").WebEdit("Test").Set "India"
WshShell.SendKeys ""
```

Note - you can also type the text instead of blank in sendkeys

You may also want to look at : 
http://www.knowledgeinbox.com/articles/qtp/settings/when-to-change-qtp-web-replaytype-setting/

Let us know if nothing works, we can try finding other solutions.